# Winter 22 Breaking apex:Map in Visualforce?

Tags: visualforce, winter22

I have a pretty simple implementation of apex:map in a VF page, and works briefly and then fails with this error:

```
HTTP ERROR 400 Bad Request
URI:    /maps/JavascriptHandler
STATUS: 400
MESSAGE:    Bad Request
SERVLET:    maps.servlet.JavascriptHandlerServlet
```

I have seen someone else report the same issue on the dev forums, so wondering if anyone else has see this in Winter22, or whether I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you please confirm if this issue is still there. There were issue in all winter 22 sandboxes but i noticed that it is resolved now.

Comment: Seems to be stable this morning...will test again later today to see if seems to be resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is identified in all Winter 22 sandboxes. This issue has been fixed by prod team .while there is no KI created for this, it has been fixed under #W-9869612